# Using of Alamofire and completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, alamofire, completionhandler

Hi everybody and great thanks for help! I'm new to programming, so sorry if smth looks stupid or weird.

I'm making login page of my app. I have 2 fields - **email** and **password**. I created a class **User** with properties **email** and **class**, bool **isLoggedIn** and func **authenticateUser**, that performs POST request.

My Logic:

1. User enters **email** and **password** and pushes Login button.
2. This creates an object of class with **isLoggedIn**'s value **false**
3. And also it performs POST request to server
4. If respond confirms such user, **isLoggedIn** changes to **true** and segue to main page is being performed.

For requests I use  Alamofire. If I understood right, I can change **isLoggedIn**'s value only by using completionhandler. But it didn't work for me - value of **isLoggedIn** doesn't change, while **resultBool** from second part of code becomes **true**.

I'm sure I have a mistake, but already 4 days I can't understand where. I would be very grateful for any kind of advise and help.

There is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


class User {


    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var email: String
    var password: String
    var isLoggedIn: Bool

    init(email: String, password: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.isLoggedIn = false
    }

    // Perform authentication
    func authenticateUser(user: User, completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> ()) {
        makeAuthenticateUserCall(user: user, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    // Perform POST request
    func makeAuthenticateUserCall(user: User, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

        let parameters = [
            "email" : user.email,
            "password" : user.password
        ]

        Alamofire.request("http://apistaging.server.com/api/v1/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON {response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                        let status = json["status"] as? String,
                        status == "success" {
                        completionHandler(true)
                    }
                case .failure:
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Code from ViewController:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let email = _email.text {
            if let password = _password.text {
                let user = User(email: email, password: password)
                user.authenticateUser(user: user) {resultBool in
                        user.isLoggedIn = resultBool
                    }
                if user.isLoggedIn {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainPageViewController", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The segue needs to be performed inside the completion handler

Comment: thanks, but why and how?

Answer (score 0):

You checked result before it's actually returned:

```
if let password = _password.text {
    let user = User(email: email, password: password)
    user.authenticateUser(user: user) {resultBool in
        user.isLoggedIn = resultBool
        if resultBool {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainPageViewController", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```